# Beside contains method, what are other alternatives to compare an arraylist with string text file?

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I have an `ArrayList` for all keywords/reserved words, but when output is printed it prints duplicate keywords and I know for a fact that I can use `HashSet` to eliminate duplicates (I've tried them all none of them worked so far). But I think the `contains` method is responsible for printing the duplicates.

Any suggestion on alternatives for `contains` methods?

I'm creating a lexical analyzer by the way and this is the sample input and output

**ArrayList:**

```
ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("auto","case","char","const","continue","default",
                            "do","double","else","break","enum","extern","float","for","goto",
                            "if","int","long","register","return","short","signed",
                            "sizeof","static","struct","switch","typedef","union",
                            "unsigned","void","volatile","while","then","int","endif"));
```

**Code for displaying:**

```
  System.out.print("Keywords:");
            for(int i =0; i<testarray.size(); i++){ 
            String gg = testarray.toString().replace(",","").replace("[","").replace("]","");

          String[] key = gg.trim().split(" ");
                 String gg1 = key[i];

                 if(keywords.contains(gg1)){

                     System.out.println(gg1+" ");
                 }
                 }
```

**Input:**

```
{

int a[3],t1,t2;

t1= 2 ; a[0]= 1; a[1]= 2; a[t1]= 3;

t2= - (a[2] + t1 * 6 ) / (a[2] - t1);

if t2 > 5 
then

print ( t2 );

else {

int t3 ; t3 = 99 ; t2 = -25 ;

print(- t1 +t2 * t3); 

} endif

}
```

**Output:**
Keywords:int if then else int endif

**Reading the file:**

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                test = line.split(" ");

                testarray.addAll(Arrays.asList(test));

            }
```

Comment: Can you add more details as to what you are trying to do?

Comment: Some code would be helpful. Because the `contains` method doesn't print anything by itself and therefor can hardly be responsible for "printing the duplicates". I suspect your own code is the culprit here.

Comment: You are using the exact same `String gg` value in each iteration. Perhaps you meant `testarray[i]` instead of just `testarray`?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException he's actually "correctly" testing different words of the input since the `gg` is split around space and later indexed with `i`. Of course the input transformation should only be done once and certainly not by using `.toString()`...

Comment: However `i` is based on `testarray.size()` (which I guess is the number of lines in the input?) rather than the number of words in `gg`, so it might not correctly process every word and will crash or crash when there's more lines than words

Comment: @bryonkurtsegunto can you add the way you're reading the input into the `testarray` to your main code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like you are doing complicated things for nothing:

**ArrayList:**

```
ArrayList<String> keywords = Arrays.asList("auto","case","char","const","continue","default",
                            "do","double","else","break","enum","extern","float","for","goto",
                            "if","int","long","register","return","short","signed",
                            "sizeof","static","struct","switch","typedef","union",
                            "unsigned","void","volatile","while","then","int","endif");
```

**Code for displaying:**

```
Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
for (String key : testarray) { 
    if(keywords.contains(key)) {
        keys.add(key);
    }
}

System.out.print("Keywords:");
for (String key : keys) {
    System.out.println(key + " ");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the unicity problem, and I suspect `testArray` is an array of lines, in which case it wouldn't work

Comment: Yeah you made it simple, but the output still prints the same.

Comment: @bryonkurtsegunto I edited the answer, tell me if it's ok now

Comment: Of course we can do better with lambda, but I don't know if op works with java 8.

Comment: @senerh the only problem I've noticed is the ordering. But, in general it solved my problem

Comment: If you want keywords in alphabetical order, you can use a `TreeSet` instead of a `HashSet`.

Comment: If you want the keywords to be printed in encounter order, that can also be done with a simple change to the code.